# Do I need transit visa at Muscat?

Tags: visas, transit, kenyan-citizens, oman, mct

I am a Kenyan planning to travel from Guangzhou airport, China to Nairobi, Kenya and back with Oman Air with a transfer at Muscat. Do I need a transit visa at Muscat?

Comment: How long is your transfer?  Are your flights all on one ticket?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ke&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=om&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for holders of onward tickets for a max.
>   transit time of 6 hours.

So, because your trip is in a single booking, you do **not** need a visa.